# Permuted block design Wilcoxon sum rank test

Tags: biostatistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, permutation-test, clinical-trials, blocking

I need to do a Wilcoxon rank sum statistic for some data with a permuted-block with 2 blocks of size 6. However, I'm confused how we deal with the permuted-block randomization.

My book says

> When permuted-block randomization is used the permutation test should
>   take the blocking into account. If blocking is ignored there is no
>   randomization basis for tests.

(and that subsequently they may not be correct). It goes on to say that for a t-test if you do not account for the blocking it means it is not necessarily going to have a t distribution but if it is it will. It however doesn't say how it accounts for it. I assume we must also account for it in the Wilcoxon test?

Here are the Data:

```
Participant 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
Assignment  1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2
Rank        12  1   11  2   10  3   9   4   8   5   6   7
Response    3.7 1.16    3.57    1.65    3.50    1.89    3.04    2.34    2.86    2.37    2.54    2.74
```